# Install Imagick in Laravel Sail (Docker)

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, laravel-sail

I am trying to install Imagick PHP Extension in Laravel Sail but I am failing to do so.

Details:
Laravel 9
PHP 8.2

In the Dockerfile (in directory docker/8.2) I added this snippet to the script:

`RUN apt-get update; \ # Imagick extension apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev; \ pecl install imagick; \ docker-php-ext-enable imagick; \ # Success true`

Did run sail build and it runs the script without errors but it does not detect Imagick

Comment: Can you try `docker-php-ext-install imagick` in stead of `pecl install imagick;` ?

Comment: @Techno: Thanks, I just had to add this line php8.2-imagick in Dockerfile and the issue was that I forgot to point to the published Dockerfile... :D

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I forgot to point to the published Dockerfile in docker-composer.yml. :/